# ¿Como seleccionar cualquier ID de mi tabla y se muestren mas detalles en otra pagina?

Tags: json, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me imprime una tabla con datos extraidos de un JSON. Lo que quiero realizar es que al dar clic a cualquier ID me redirija a otra a pagina para ver mas detalles del usuario. Soy nuevo en React y he estado viendo ejemplos, ya se como extraer el ID al hacer clic pero no al pasarlos a otro componente.

```
import Data from '../components/users.json';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


export default withAuth(class Users extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ marginTop: '150px' }}>
                <div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Last Updated</th>
                        </tr>
                        {Data.map((user, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={user.id}>
                                    <td>{user.id}</td>
                                    <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                                    <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                                    <td>{user.lastUpdated}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: como lo solucionaste a mi me sale el siguiente error en mi map de la pagina destino ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined (anonymous function) C:/Users/Nicolas Esquivel/Desktop/DWC/src/components/Detail/index.js:19 return ( <section> {items .filter(item => item.id == props.match.params.id) .map(item => (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno la solución a tu problema esta en utilizar `Link` que nos proporciona el paquete `react-router-dom`

Por ejemplo podemos registrar una url que reciba el id del usuario y despues mostrar la informacion del dicho usuario.

NOTA: Ejemplo de blog.

```
<Switch>
  //Ruta donde mostramos todos los posts
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  //Ruta donde mostraremos solo un post
  <Route exact path="/blog/:id" component={Blog} />
</Switch>
```

Despues en nuestro componente Home, mostramos todos los posts que tenemos.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const items = require("../blog.json");

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    {items.map((item, key) => (
      <div>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <Link
          to={{
            //Pasamos el id como parametro.
            pathname: `/blog/${item.id}`,
            state: { id: item.id }
          }}
        >
          Ver mas
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Fijate que estamos utilizando el componente **Link** para que cuando el usuario haga click en ver mas le lleve a la página del post unico.

Ahora en el componente **Blog** simplemente recogemos ese id y obtenemos el unico post que nos interesa ver.

```
import React from "react";

const items = require("../blog.json");

const Blog = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items
        .filter(item => item.id == props.match.params.id)
        .map(item => (
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

En cualquier caso te he hecho un [Ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jzkwwy4kmw?fontsize=14) para que lo puedas ver mejor y testear.

La otra opcion que tienes es utilizando directamente el HOC withRouter.

[Ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooqm21kq96?fontsize=14):

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const items = require("../blog.json");

const Home = ({ history }) => (
  <div>
    {items.map((item, key) => (
      <div>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => history.push(`/blog/${item.id}`)}>Ver mas</button>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Espero que me haya explicado bien y sobre todo hazme saber si te funciona.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Creo ya esta solucionado a un 50%, cuando pongo la ruta directamente supongamos /Details/00ub0oNGTSWTBKOLGLNR
ya me trae los valores de ese ID. Pero cuando le doy clic a mi tabla la ruta que manda es esta siempre, por lo que no carga nada. /Details/$%7Buser.id%7D pareciera que convierte paretensis y demas a codigo ascii o algo parecido

Comment: Eran las comillas, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado. Respecto a las comillas(template string) te recomiendo que te vayas acostumbrando a utilizarlas ya que se utilizan mucho con react.  Saludos!!!